# Compiling J2ME from command prompt

Tags: java, java-me, cmd

I'm trying to compile the J2ME java files from command line from 2 week ago !at now I can compile project successfully and also create JAR and JAD files . The files that I compile work equivocal, this means if I use basic class the same as TextField or Form or others this work successfully but if I use RecordStores OR more important if use Resource(s) AND Library(s) the result is not good and program can not work.

Comment: Perhaps if you pasted the commands that you are using in your question, we could see where you may be going wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not know what 'compiling from command prompt' means, but You should really take a look at [Ant](http://ant.apache.org/) and it's extension [Antenna](http://antenna.sourceforge.net/) for J2ME apps building.

Antenna should be really easy one for starting the development and just for compiling/creating distribution package. And it makes including thirdparty jars just a breeze :)

Besides using some IDE plugins I'm sure you will not get a better answer then this.

/Jaanus

Comment: hi, but i can not use ant . do you have any idea ? i am using WTK22 Document for compile j2me code from cmd,you can see it in (WTK22/docs/UserGuide.pdf) and also you can download it here (http://rapidshare.com/files/239272180/Command_Line_Reference.pdf.html) please . ( excuse me for my poor english ) Thanks and Regards

Comment: This is a really stupid question - why can't you use ant? It is also running on command line :)

Comment: ok but for using ant we must create a "xml" file that i can not do this !! but jaanus, you say i cannot using javac for compile j2me Codes ? i think WTK22 use javac to do this , No ?

Comment: I'm sorry, I have no idea what You are trying to do :) 

If you can't create xml files, how are you creating source (java) files? :P

Comment: thank you jaanus , i solve my problem and also to soon i release my beta version !!
i want you see it so i send you a message soon :)
thank you a lot !!!

Comment: @dashtebash can you share your idea of this question? how to compile j2me code with `javac` and packet.